# How to set a cell unconnectable dynamically？

Tags: javascript, mxgraph

I create cells with some ports:

1. How can I set the input-port unconnectable when the income-edges are more than the input-ports?
2. How to disable a cell connect with the cell of given type?

I find a class `mxMultiplicity`, it seems to be helpful, but I don't know how to use it.

The XML expression of the graph is like this. There are two kinds of cells, they have user object `Table` and `Operation` as value.

```html
<mxGraphModel>
  <root>
    <mxCell id="0"/>
    <mxCell id="1" parent="0"/>
    <mxCell id="2" style="table" vertex="1" parent="1">
      <Table name="table1" as="value">
        <Array as="data">
          <add value="1"/>
          <add value="2"/>
          <add value="3"/>
        </Array>
      </Table>
      <mxGeometry x="90" y="50" width="50" height="50" as="geometry"/>
      <Array as="ports">
        <Object type="out" x="0.5" y="0.5" perimeter="1"/>
      </Array>
    </mxCell>
    <mxCell id="3" vertex="1" parent="1">
      <Operation name="add" portNumber="2" code="a + b" as="value"/>
      <mxGeometry x="150" y="180" width="90" height="50" as="geometry"/>
      <Array as="ports">
        <Object type="in" x="0.3" y="0" perimetry="1" as="add-in0"/>
        <Object type="in" x="0.6" y="0" perimetry="1" as="add-in1"/>
        <Object type="out" x="0.5" y="1" perimetry="1" as="add-out"/>
      </Array>
    </mxCell>
  </root>
</mxGraphModel>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by myself, hope the answer can help you if you have the same question.

I checked the code of `mxMultiplicity.js`, and tried to override the prototype function `checkType`. In this way, when it check if the teminal you connect with is the disable cell, if the `value` is an object, it will check if `value` is instance of the `type`.

```js
mxMultiplicity.prototype.checkType = function(graph, value, type, attr, attrValue) {
            if (value != null) {
                if (typeof value == 'object') {
                    if (value instanceof type) {
                        return value[attr] == attrValue;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                } else if (!isNaN(value.nodeType)) {
                    return mxUtils.isNode(value, type, attr, attrValue);
                } else {
                    return value == type;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
```

The connection rule can be this, and `Table` is my constructor.

```js
graph.multiplicities.push(new mxMultiplicity(
    false, Table, null, null, 0, 0, null,
    'can not input to table', 'null'
));
```

Answer (score 0):

we can use `mxGraph.prototype.validateEdge` and need to implementation.

```
mxGraph.prototype.validateEdge = function(edge, source, target)
{
    // to do implementation.

    // return type : to be "String" or "Null"
    return null;
};
```